# Is it possible to take 2 columns from File 1, find them in File 2 and extract the relevant lines from File 2 into File 3?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have 2 text files. File1 has about 1,000 lines and File2 has 20,000 lines. An extract of File1 is as follows:

```
 /BBC Micro/Thrust
 /Amiga/Alien Breed Special Edition '92
 /Arcade-Vertical/amidar
 /MAME (Advance)/mario
 /Arcade-Vertical/mspacman
 /Sharp X68000/Bubble Bobble (1989)(Dempa)
 /BBC Micro/Chuckie Egg
```

An extract of File2 is as follows:

```
 005;005;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Amiga;;1992;Team 17;Action / Shooter;;;;;;;;;;
 Alien 8 (Japan);Alien 8 (Japan);msx;;1987;Nippon Dexter Co., Ltd.;Action;1;;;;;;;;;
 amidar;amidar;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Bubble Bobble (Japan);Bubble Bobble (Japan);msx2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Buffy the Vampire Slayer - Wrath of the Darkhul King (USA, Europe);Buffy the Vampire Slayer - Wrath of the Darkhul King (USA, Europe);Nintendo Game Boy Advance;;2003;THQ;Action;;;;;;;;;;
 mario;mario;FBA;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 mspacman;mspacman;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Thunder Blade (1988)(U.S. Gold)[128K];Thunder Blade (1988)(U.S. Gold)[128K];ZX Spectrum;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Thunder Mario v0.1 (SMB1 Hack);Thunder Mario v0.1 (SMB1 Hack);Nintendo NES Hacks 2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 Thrust;Thrust;Vectrex;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

In File3 (the output file), using grep, sed, awk or a bash script, I would like to achieve the following output:

```
  Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Amiga;;1992;Team 17;Action / Shooter;;;;;;;;;;
  amidar;amidar;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  mspacman;mspacman;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

This is similar to a previous question I asked but not the same.  I specifically want to avoid the possibility of Thrust;Thrust;Vectrex;;;;;;;;;;;;;; being recorded in File 3.

Using sudo awk -F\; 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1]}', I found that  Thrust;Thrust;Vectrex;;;;;;;;;;;;;; was recorded in File 3 instead of Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;;;;;; (the latter being the output I'm seeking).

Equally, mario;mario;FBA;;;;;;;;;;;;;; won't appear in File3 because it does not match /MAME (Advance)/mario as "MAME (Advance)" doesn't match.  That is good.  The same for Bubble Bobble (Japan);Bubble Bobble (Japan);msx2;;;;;;;;;;;;;; which doesn't match either "Sharp X68000" or "Bubble Bobble (1989)(Dempa)".

Comment: The criteria for selecting lines are not at all clear. Using `;` as the FS, $1 of file1 is the whole line. Please spell out in detail how to select lines from file2 based on contents of file1

Comment: For example, if both the 1st and 2nd columns of File 1 (eg BBC Micro and Thrust) are found on a single line in File 2 (eg Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;), then that line (Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;) will be recorded in File 3.  The line in File 2, being Thrust;Thrust;Vectrex;;;;;;;; will not be recorded in File 3 because it does not match BBC Micro.

Comment: You were correct.  Sorry about that.  I needed to change File3 to reflect the correct output.

Comment: It appears that you can match "column 2" in file1 with the 1st field in file2, and "column 1" in file2 with the 3rd field in file2. Is that your rules for matching? Or, as you say, the data from file2 just has to "match"?

Comment: Thanks, Glenn.  That is a correct summary of what I'm looking for.  Sorry about the question not being clear.

Comment: I should say, Glenn, "yes" to your first question, just in case my response was not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using AWK and associative array You can use this:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  if ( ARGC != 3 ) exit(1);
  FS="/";
  while ( getline < ARGV[2] ) mfggames[$2"/"$3]=1;
  FS=";";
  ARGC=2;
}
mfggames[$3"/"$1]
' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Amiga;;1992;Team 17;Action / Shooter;;;;;;;;;;
amidar;amidar;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mspacman;mspacman;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Sorted per file1 solution (as per comment request):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  if ( ARGC != 3 ) exit(1);
  FS="/";
  while ( getline < ARGV[2] ) mfggames[$2"/"$3]=++order;
  FS=";";
  ARGC=2;
}
mfggames[$3"/"$1] { print(mfggames[$3"/"$1] FS $0); }
' file2 file1 | sort -n | cut -d ';' -f 2-
```

Output:

```
Thrust;Thrust;BBC Micro;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Alien Breed Special Edition '92;Amiga;;1992;Team 17;Action / Shooter;;;;;;;;;;
amidar;amidar;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mspacman;mspacman;Arcade-Vertical;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Thanks, Kubator.  But I need the order to be in the same order as I have it - ie same order as File1/File3 - not sorted as in your Output.

Comment: Basically, File1 needs to dictate the file order.

Comment: OK, added as "Sorted per file1 solution" in my answer. Unfortunately this wan't emphasized in original question.

Comment: Thank you.  That does appear to work for me.  Could I ask please whether it is possible to have this code on one line?  If not, that is fine. I will upvote your solution.  Thank you again.

Comment: One line? Yes just remove NLs: awk 'BEGIN { if ( ARGC != 3 ) exit(1); FS="/"; while ( getline < ARGV[2] ) mfggames[$2"/"$3]=++order; FS=";"; ARGC=2; } mfggames[$3"/"$1] { print(mfggames[$3"/"$1] FS $0); }' file2 file1 | sort -n | cut -d ';' -f 2-